# Exif Data READ Write

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, exif

i am trying to write exif data into a image . 
I am trying to code it in Flash builder. Thus it seems like actionscript is the only choice.

I have found libraries from java. But it doesnt fit it in flash builder.

Anybody have any clues ?

yweeeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](http://code.google.com/p/as3-xmp-file/) library?

Comment: tried it, but it is using XML to read and write. i am using flash builder, and i cant seems to be able to import com.adobe.xmp.*;

Comment: It uses XML because that is what exif data is.

Comment: i cant seems to get the XMP Core library that it states there, the link is redirected to [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) and Tried downloading the SDK, its all java files, doesnt seems to work with the API

Comment: do u have any idea how to implement the writing/update of exif with that library?